# There is a TODO at the bottom of each question page

Tags: bug

at the bottom of each question page there is the following TODO visible:
// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident in our current implementation of async imports // once we are, we can move the if into the js entry file and dynamically load the mark obsolete module